# Rename file with same name present in sub folders to include sub folder name

Tags: linux, unix, rename, mv

There are multiple folders ..folder1, folder2..foldern and each folder has many files but there is one file with name sample.txt which is present in each and every folder.

Is there a way to rename all the sample.txt such that they are renamed to name of parent folder
eg. folder1/sample.txt ->folder1.txt 
folder2/sample.txt ->folder2.txt
..
foldern/sample.txt -> foldern.txt

Comment: Take a look at the `find` utility, you should be able to combine its `exec` feature with the `sed` processor for this.

Answer (score 0):

FILES=$PWD/Feline_combined/*/

for f in $FILES

do

cd $f

test=${PWD##*/}

echo $test

cp fastqjoin.join.fastq ~/Desktop/Shared_Folder/Project_VRB/shell/$test.fastq

done